# Material UI Autocomplete getOptionSelected function seems to be failing, I need guidance

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I am using MUI's Autocomplete component in a multi-step form

```js
<Controller
                name="genderId"
                control={control}
                render={({ field: { value, onChange } }) => (
                  <Autocomplete
                    getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value}
                    value={value}
                    getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
                    options={genderTypes}
                    onChange={(e, v) => setValue('genderId', v.id)}
                    renderInput={(params) => (
                      <TextField
                        fullWidth
                        label="Gender"
                        variant="outlined"
                        {...params}
                      />
                    )}
                  />
                )}
              />
```

My Options are in this array
[{id: 17, name: 'Male'},{id: 18,name:'Female'}]
When populate this form and go to the next step, the state is updated with the form values. The problem is that when I go back to step I get Material-UI warning about the value supplied not having a matching option and the field is blank.

[Error And Warning about supplied value in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLysV.png)
I can solve this by using the whole object instead of just the id but it will save me some lines of code if I only post the id. So what am I doing wrong ? Please help.

Comment: `console.log(genderTypes)` and show me the result.

Comment: [{id:17,name:'Male',..},{id:18,name:'Female'}]